# Port forward for mysql replication (within docker)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Sorry if I'm doing a mistake, it's my first post.

**My question**

How to configure Master/Slave mysql db to change port where master send data (I would like port 3307 instead of 3306) ?

I need to do that to have multiple slave db.

**Configuration**

So I have a [schema of my replication environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID5xu.png).

And a [part of my Docker compose yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URIBw.png).

With Ports :

```
php_my_admin:
  ports:
    - '8081:80'

db_caucasus:
  ports:
    - '3307:3307'
```

To start master/slave replication I did :

```
stop slave;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='11.111.111.01', MASTER_USER='db-rep', MASTER_PASSWORD='001', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000111', MASTER_LOG_POS= 111, MASTER_PORT=3306;
start slave;
```

And after that :

- server-id on master db is correctly 777
- `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on slave db is ok (Slave_IO_Running : OK, Slave_SQL_Running : OK, same Master_Log_File and same Read_Master_Log_Pos)

When I modifiy data on master db, I can see that replication data are send to **port 3306** (for example with the commands below)

```
tcpdump -A port 3306 and host 11.111.111.01
tcpdump -A port 3307 and host 11.111.111.01
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

You would have to link both mysql  master and slave in the docker-compose. If both the master and slave are properly configured they should communicate without a problem.

```
mysql_slave:
     ports:
        - "3307:3307"
mysql_master:
     ports:
        - "3306:3306"
     links:
        - mysql_slave
```